# Can I pass the viewbag value to the jQuery in mvc2

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I need to pass the value to jQuery in the view using viewbag. What I want to achieve is pass the null or some value and then jQuery should hide or show the div depending on the value passed for instance something like below:

```
viewbag.testNumber = null;
 $('#showdiv').hide();
  $('viewbag.testNumber').value == someinteger{

    $("#showdiv").show();
    else
    $("#showdiv").hide();
});
   <div id="showdiv"> Some Calculation </div>
```

Also I want to disable the viewbag in the view if the value is null , because it gives null error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ViewBag is only in ASP.NET MVC 3 so you can't use that, but you can use ViewData:

```
    $('#showdiv').hide();
      if ($("#" + '<%=ViewData["testNumber"]').value == someinteger){      
         $("#showdiv").show();
       }
        else {
            $("#showdiv").hide();
        }
    });
       <div id="showdiv"> Some Calculation </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are **using MVC3** (Doesn't work with 2) you can easily use ViewBag as below, but remember two points that are easy to forget and can cause headache:

1. Never put semicolon at the end of @ViewBag.myVariable
2. If you are passing string put " before and after your @ViewBag.myVariable. For example:

This is right:

```
$(function () {
    var path = "@ViewBag.helpPath"
    path = "@Url.Content("~/route/action/")" + path;
    $('#help-content').load(path);

});
```

However if you use:

```
$(function () {
    var path = @ViewBag.helpPath
    path = "@Url.Content("~/route/action/")" + path;
    $('#help-content').load(path);

});
```

MVC changes this to:

```
$(function () {
    var path = c:\\doc\\path
    path = "@Url.Content("~/route/action/")" + path;
    $('#help-content').load(path);

});
```

Which JavaScript cannot parse it, and the result would be some ugly bug. Just something I did and wasted my time thought to share it.

Comment: Removing that semi-colon at the end of @ViewBag.variable really made all the different. I had a string like "<div id="someID">We've deleted your account!</div>" and if I used double quotes to wrap the variable it expected the semi-colon before >> id=" <<if I used single quotes to wrap the variable it expected the semi-colon after >> We' << ....Removing the semicolon entirely fixed it! Thanks!

Comment: And I also had to wrap the variable in single quotes or it broke again! Wow these little nuances mixing razor and js are pretty ridiculous.  var html = '@ViewData["ViewResult"]'   <<< That's the only way it worked.

Answer (score 1):

in razor you'd just do @ViewBag.Variable_Name . I do it in my code.

Comment: And can you disable the viewbag if its value is null coz it wont bind if the value of null is pass to viewbag

Comment: mvc2 doesn't have ViewBag afaik. You'd have to use ViewData. You could first check if the key exists in the ViewData then do the javascript if it does either wise some other action?

Answer (score 1):

You could do that in your View:

```
$('#showdiv').hide();
  $('@Viewbag.testNumber').value == someinteger{

    $("#showdiv").show();
    else
    $("#showdiv").hide();
});
   <div id="showdiv"> Some Calculation </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For your MVC2 JavaScript just write the variable straight out, obviously you cant use ViewBag so:

```
var testNumber = <%:ViewData["VariableName"]%>;
```