# Toggle div depending on controller variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

### EDITED

I have a "Save Changes" button that I want to click and toggle a div with the message "Changes saved". I do it like this:

**HTML**:

```
<input type="submit" id="savebtn" name="save" value="Save Changes"/>
<input type="hidden" id="res" name="res" value="@ViewBag.result"/>
<div class="success">Changes saved</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#saveButton').click(function () {

var aux = res.value.toString();

if ($('#res').val() == "OK")
    $(".success").show();

    alert(aux);

});
```

However, I need the button to actually save the changes and, if the operation was successful, then show the message div. So, in my `cshtml` file I have a result variable that contains the success or failure of the operation.

**CSHTML**:

```
ViewBag.result = result;
```

Now, I need to show that message div depending on the result variable: I need to somehow make it a parameter for the `JQuery` function. I'm passing it in a `ViewBag`.

**NOTE:** when the page loads, the viewbag is empty. It only gets its value after the button click. And after that, the viewbag is filled and I wanted it to be used in the jQuery function but I'm not getting any luck.

Comment: can you save this variable to hidden input in html code?

Comment: You mean, pass it in a ViewBag into a hidden div for example?

Answer (score 0):

Pass that result in  a `viewbag`,

Acces that viewbag value in jquery and `show/hide` your div accordingly

Comment: it doesn't work, `I'm getting Conditional compilation is turned off as a warning`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can store the result in input hidden field, use below query to access result and initially success div is hidden :

```
<input type="hidden" id="result" value"success"/>
```

jQuery :

```
$(function(){
    if($('#result').val()=="success")
       $(".success").show();
});
```

Comment: Can't I do something like `$('#savebtn').click(function () {
        if ($(@ViewBag.result == "OK") {
            alert('test');
            }

        });`

Comment: ACtually you need to use ViewData see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521286/can-i-pass-the-viewbag-value-to-the-jquery-in-mvc2

Answer (score 0):

you can check it in a simple if condition

```
if($('#result').val()=="success")
   $(".success").toggle();
```

or You can use Ajax method

```
     function Save() {

            $.ajax({
                url: "Your Url",   // Current Page, Method  
                data: Your data // better if you parameter map as JSON  
                type: "POST",   
                contentType: "application/json", // posting JSON content      
                dataType: "JSON",  // type of data is JSON (must be upper case!)  
                timeout: 100000,    // AJAX timeout  

                success: function (result) {

                   $(".success").toggle();

                },
                error: function (xhr, status) {

                       alert("An error occurred while processing");
                }
            });

        }
```

Now call this save() in your button click